# Function works outside For loop but not inside, and loop fails spectacularly

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I'm building two lists, each to carry a different representation of the same set of objects. One list, `list2`, is constructed first; then the second list, `list1`, is built element-by-element using a translation function `TwoQOneQ`. That function relies on a second function, `ExtractList`, that takes as argument an integer and returns a unique list of three integers . All the machinery works as expected for a single argument, e.g.

```
In[93]:= 
TwoQOneQ[list2[[2]]]
TwoQOneQ[list2[[3]]]

Out[93]= {{2, 1, 2}}

Out[94]= {{1, 1, 2}}
```

as required.

However, when I embed `TwoQOneQ` inside a `For` loop, the loop runs only once:

```
For[i = 2, i <= 5, i++,
 Print[i];
 Print[TwoQOneQ[list2[[i]]]]]

2

{{2,1,2}}
```

When I comment out the line with `TwoQOneQ`, the loop runs as expected:

```
For[i = 2, i <= 5, i++,
 Print[i]]
(*Print[TwoQOneQ[list2[[i]]]]]*)

2

3

4

5
```

Also, when I increase the ceiling on `i` to `i <= 6` or higher, Mathematica freezes. The icon at the bottom of my screen has a yellow circle to say the program's running code, but the grey cell bar on the side isn't black to say it is; the scroll bar rapidly shrinks as if there's a large amount of output, but nothing prints; and I have to close Mathematica through the Task Manager.

The full, simplified code is

```
ExtractList = 
  Function[k, {Mod[k - 1, 2] + 1, Mod[Quotient[k - 1, 2], 1] + 1, 
    Quotient[k - 1, 2] + 1}];

list2 = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];
list1 = Table[{0}, {i, 0}];

(*translates a given state in second list into a given state in first list*)
TwoQOneQ = Function[TwoQ,
   OneQ = Table[{0}, {i, 0}];
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[TwoQ], i++,
    If[TwoQ[[i]] == 1, OneQ = Append[OneQ, ExtractList[i]], 
     OneQ = OneQ]];
   OneQ];


For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
 Print[i]]
 Print[TwoQOneQ[list2[[i]]]]]
```

This problem has persisted through restarting Mathematica and restarting my computer.

Comment: I presume what's going on is that `For` does not localise its variables -- `i` appears multiple times here, and it is always the exact same object.

Comment: This appears to be a scoping problem. Your variable `i` is not localalized, and is changed by the function TwoQOneQ.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform is right. Try `Table[TwoQOneQ[list2[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]`.

Comment: All three of you are right! The change works. @AccidentalFourierTransform was first; if you post your comment as a response I'll accept it as the answer.